# Matlab - Plot histogram of oriented gradients with external feature Vector

Tags: matlab, image-processing, plot, feature-extraction

A hardware design does calculate a normalised hog feature vector, which I want to visualise with the Matlab Hog library.

```
fpga_normArr =  'Output_Norm_FPGA.txt';
delimiterIn = '\n';
headerlinesIn = 0;
A = importdata(fpga_normArr,delimiterIn,headerlinesIn);

% want to give following function extractHOGFeatures "A" Vector as Input .. ?
img = imread('output_cropped.jpeg');
[_, hogVisualization] = extractHOGFeatures(fpga_normArr);
%override the hogVisualization output and plot the modified object?
plot(hogVisualization)
```

Is there a function in Matlab, which is able to plot a given feature vector?

Edit: I'm open for alternative approaches, perhabs on different platforms